# SelfSSL7 for CN = localhost and MachineName

Tags: ssl, iis-7.5, ssl-certificate, certificate

I'm trying to create a cert for the default web site on my local dev server using selfssl7

I ran the following and it generates a cert for the machiname ( visible under "server certificates" in IIS)
SelfSSL7 /N:cn="localhost",cn="My Machine name"  /K 1024 /V 18250 /I /S "Default Web Site" /T /Q

SSL works if I hit the site using the machine: "https://My Machine name"
but "https://localhost" does not work
The message I get is:
"The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address."

How can I make SSL work using both the machine name and localhost?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:
SelfSSL7 /Q /T /I "Default Web Site" /N cn=Machine Name;cn=localhost

This registers both the machine name and localhost in the cert