# Wireless Profile via Group Policy - Specific Trusted Root not Listed?

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, wifi, 802.1

[image: Add to trusted root certification authorities?]

So I am trying to use Group Policy to configure the wireless settings on a bunch of laptops. We are using a third party cert that isn't showing up as an option in the list of Trusted Root Certification Authorities. This is stopping us from configuring our machines to use certificates to authenticate.

Does anybody know how to add more trusted roots to this list in the Group Policy editor?
How does the Protected EAP Properties panel generate this list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In-house Trusted Certificate](http://serverfault.com/questions/143047/in-house-trusted-certificate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to deploy the trusted root certificate, you can do so using group policy:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738131(v=ws.10).aspx

You navigate to:

`Policy Object Name/Computer Configuration/Windows Settings/Security Settings/Public Key Policies/Trusted Root Certification Authorities`

in a GPO that applies to the computers in question and import the third party certificate that you want added to the trusted store.

If you want that same trusted Root Certificate to appear in the list of available certificated when doing the PEAP setup, import it as a trusted certificate on the domain controllers which you are connecting to with GPMC.  But it will also most definitely need to be deployed to the clients with the above listed steps before it will be able to be applied to the PEAP properties.

Comment: importing the cert will add it to the list when I attempt to configure the group policy?

I am able to see it in the list if I configure the wireless settings at the client level.

Comment: ok, so yes we did import the cert into the GPO, but it is still not showing up as a configurable option in the GPO.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood.  Is the certificate imported into the Trusted store on all domain controllers and on the workstation you are running GPMC on?

Comment: Importing the Cert into the Store of the PDC resolved the issue, thanks!